# DataGrid hierarchical in UWP

Tags: uwp

I need a solution for a hierarchical DataGrid in UWP. I'm looking for something that works like telerik's radTreeListView. I need to migrate the behavior of radTreeListView for UWP.

Comment: You have to custom your DataGrid to implement similar behavior.

Comment: I don't think custom a datagrid could do that. You can do it in WPF using radTreeListView and package your app as UWP if you want to publish your app to the store.